# Disable sr-only span element using Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

Font Awesome is adding a hidden span element with the name of the icon in it.

Example:

```
<span class="sr-only">Camera</span>
```

How can I tell Font Awesome not to render this element (disable this feature). I am using the official [Font Awesome script](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set alternative text, Then you can use **aria-hidden="true"** attribute.

**sr-only** is for screen reader purpose. Don't remove it.

You can add custom CSS for change/disable **sr-only** property.

**Here is an Example**

```
.sr-only {
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: -1px;
   overflow: hidden;
   clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
   border: none;
}
```

You can get more details for Font Awesome **sr-only** class from [Here](http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/)